# My 1992 Volvo 940 Turbo won't Accelerate

Tags: volvo, fuel-injection

It 
will start, idle, rev up to 6,000 RPM in park or neutral but as soon as you put it in gear and step on the accelerator it dies or chugs ? PS: Limp mode does the same !

Comment: Which fuel does it use?

Comment: High octane/High test gasoline...just had the shop replace the in tank fuel pump...didn't help ?

Comment: I don't know if you even put a timing light on this computer controlled timing....I did, and it seems to retard when revved instead of advance ???

Comment: I would start by checking the crank/cam position sensors.

Comment: @user12571  Have you resolved the issue or do you still have it?